# Lua get class name of object at runtime

Tags: lua, runtime, classname

im wondering if there is way to get class name of object at runtime.
i mean something like this:
here is my very simple script

```
person=TPerson:new()
```

And i want in my app (in delphi) get "TPerson"
I tried it with lua debug info but what i know to get is called function "new" but i need to get class "TPerson"

```
 lua_getstack(l,0,PL_Debug); 
 lua_getfield(l,LUA_GLOBALSINDEX,'f');
 lua_getinfo(l,'n',PL_Debug);   
 nameOfCurrnetFunction:=PL_Debug.name; // here is stored "new"
```

so is possible to get class name?
thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Officially you do not have classes in Lua so the type of your objects would always be table. Of course you are free to implement some function that returns you a custom type-name as a string. Lua-wise it will remain a table tough

Comment: In Lua 5.3, for classes created with `luaL_newmetatable(L,name)`, the `name` is stored in the metatable as `__name`.